# How to display the menu list from API in DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native

I have created the side menu using DrawerNavigator with the static menu names and screens. I want the menu names and screens to be dynamic. Meaning to say I like to fetch those details in API and display in the DrawerNavigator. Please help to resolve this.

```
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({   
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  WebMenuScreen: {
    screen: WebMenuScreen,
  },
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'right',
},{
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will helps you.

in Route File

```
import DrawerNavigator from "./DrawerNavigator";
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About'
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from "react-navigation";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  DrawerNavigator: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      htitle: 'Home'
    }
  },
  About: {
    screen: About,
    navigationOptions: {
      htitle: 'About'
    }
  },
});

const Routes = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default Routes;
```

in DrawerNavigator File

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './Home';
import About from '/About'
import MenuDrawer from './MenuDrawer';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
    contentComponent: ({ navigation }) => {
        return(<MenuDrawer navigation={navigation} />)
    }
}

const DrawerNavigator =  createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home:{
            screen:Home
        },
        About:{
            screen:About
        },
    },
    DrawerConfig
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

in Menu Drawer File

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"Home","name":"About" }');
// import styles from './menuDrawerStyles'

class MenuDrawer extends React.Component {


  navLink(nav, text) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ height: 50 }}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(nav)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.link}>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroller}>

          {
            this.obj.map((data) => {
              <View style={styles.bottomLinks}>
                <View style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: "row" }}>

                  {this.navLink(data.name, data.name)}
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: "row" }}>

                {this.navLink(data.name, data.name)}
                </View>


              </View>
            })
          }

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

in Menu Button File

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet , Platform } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";

export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Icon
        name="reorder"
        color="black"
        size={25}
        style={styles.menuIcon}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuIcon: {
    zIndex: 9,
    position: "absolute",
    top: Platform.OS === "android" ? 15 : 25,
    left: 20
  }
});
```

In Menu Drawer file you can call Api and fetch menu list.